# Permission on Database

Tags: sql-server, permissions, users

I have a login user called TestUser created at the server level that is assigned to a read only role, now I need to create a user for the TestUser login on MyDb

```
USE [MyDB]
GO
CREATE USER [Test] FOR LOGIN [TestUser]
GO
GRANT SELECT TO [Test]
GO
DENY DELETE TO [Test]
GO
DENY INSERT TO [Test]
GO
DENY UPDATE TO [Test]
GO
```

everything is good but when I script that Test user created, I don't see in any place the script that I'm giving select and denying insert, delete and update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a login user called TestUser created at the server level that
>   is assigned to a read only role

There is no any `fixed server role` that can be called "read only role".

Maybe your `@@version` >= `2014` and you granted `select all user securables` to your login?

If so, this server level permission can be seen this way:

```
select class_desc, permission_name, state_desc
from sys.server_permissions
where suser_name(grantee_principal_id) = 'Test';
---------------------------------------------------
--class_desc    permission_name state_desc
--SERVER    CONNECT SQL GRANT
--SERVER    SELECT ALL USER SECURABLES  GRANT
```

Then you did some unnecessary `grant`/`deny`, you should not did it. When you map your login that has `select all user securables` this user already access any data in this database, so there is no need in additional `SELECT` permission.

Also there is no need to `deny` other rights as the newly created `user` does not have any of this `permission`.

But if you want to check that they were `granted`/`denied` you should select from `sys.database_permissions` like so:

```
select class_desc, permission_name, state_desc
from sys.database_permissions
where user_name(grantee_principal_id) = 'Test';
---------------------------------------------------
--class_desc    permission_name state_desc
--DATABASE  CONNECT GRANT
--DATABASE  DELETE  DENY
--DATABASE  INSERT  DENY
--DATABASE  SELECT  GRANT
--DATABASE  UPDATE  DENY
```

You can script `server level permissions` as well as `database level permissions` using `sys.server_permissions` / `sys.database_permissions`, in your simple case when the securable is `database` the script can look like this:

```
select state_desc +'  ' + permission_name + ' to Test'
from sys.database_permissions
where user_name(grantee_principal_id) = 'Test'
      and permission_name <> 'connect';
```

Here is the complete script to test:

```
create login Test with password = '*****', check_policy = off;
grant select all user securables to Test;

select class_desc, permission_name, state_desc
from sys.server_permissions
where suser_name(grantee_principal_id) = 'Test';
---------------------------------------------------
--class_desc    permission_name state_desc
--SERVER    CONNECT SQL GRANT
--SERVER    SELECT ALL USER SECURABLES  GRANT

use MyDB;
create user Test from login Test;

select class_desc, permission_name, state_desc
from sys.database_permissions
where user_name(grantee_principal_id) = 'Test';
---------------------------------------------------
--class_desc    permission_name state_desc
--DATABASE  CONNECT GRANT

GRANT SELECT TO [Test]
GO
DENY DELETE TO [Test]
GO
DENY INSERT TO [Test]
GO
DENY UPDATE TO [Test]
GO

select class_desc, permission_name, state_desc
from sys.database_permissions
where user_name(grantee_principal_id) = 'Test';
---------------------------------------------------
--class_desc    permission_name state_desc
--DATABASE  CONNECT GRANT
--DATABASE  DELETE  DENY
--DATABASE  INSERT  DENY
--DATABASE  SELECT  GRANT
--DATABASE  UPDATE  DENY

select state_desc +'  ' + permission_name + ' to Test'
from sys.database_permissions
where user_name(grantee_principal_id) = 'Test'
      and permission_name <> 'connect';
```

Comment: Thank you everybody for the time you spend on this for me, very appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

Most probably because you are using the generate scripts method to do so.

I would suggest to use open source [DBA tools](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Export-DbaUser) to view the permission or export.

**Aliases :** Export-SqlUser

**Synopsis**

Exports users creation and its permissions to a T-SQL file or host.

**Description**

Exports users creation and its permissions to a T-SQL file or host. Export includes user, create and add to role(s), database level permissions, object level permissions.

Example:

> PS C:> Export-DbaUser -SqlInstance sqlserver2014a -User User1, User2
>   -Path C:\temp\users.sql

Exports ONLY users User1 and User2 from sqlserver2014a to the file C:\temp\users.sql

Comment: is it probably Export-DbaUser?

Comment: One more question, can we install this in a prod server?

Comment: Yes it's widely used and recommended by community. As always said, test in lower environments and go to prod from there. Visit dbatools security page to get more clarification on this